# Error trying to insert custom link in page layout in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I just created a custom link to a salesforce report

```
/xxxxxx/?pv0={!Account.Id}
```

But when i insert this custom link on the account page layout and click the link it shows error

```
URL No Longer Exists
```

I even tried to preview the custom link but it also shows the same error.
Can any one point out what may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need last "/" :)

Try with `/xxxxxx?pv0={!Account.Id}` ?

Comment: Thnks dat worked but now i'm getting error "Unable to Access Page" while trying to preview the page layout but the preview of custom link is working.

Comment: Preview is a bit buggy ;) Just check if it behaves as you want if you click the link on actual account's page?

Comment: No probs :) It's always small things like that. You crack your head for hours, frustrated show it to somebody and he points out something obvious ;) Glad I could help!